# построение маршрута в Yandex Maps JS API V3

Tags: yandex-maps-api

При использовании Yandex Maps JS API V3 планирую сделать кнопку построения маршрута до маркера. Но что-то нигде в мануалах не нашел, как это сделать. Плохо искал или в третью версию АПИ маршрутизацию не завезли?

Comment: и кому нужна эта версия 3.0 без маршрутов?((( печалька

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Версия JS API 3.0 сейчас не включает в себя всех возможностей предыдущей версии 2.1 продукта. Панели маршрутизации и встроенных методов прокладывания маршрута в ней пока нет.

Но обязательно рассмотрим возможность добавления маршрутов в будущих версиях сервиса.

Comment: спасибо, жаль. правильно ли я понимаю, что по крайней мере пока этого функционала не появится в API 3.0, предыдущая версия API (2.x) будет доступна? Спасибо

Comment: С выходом новых версий браузеров и веб-стандартов вы можете столкнуться с неполадками в работе старых версий сервиса. Но планов отключать в обозримом будущем версию 2.1 нет. До сих пор работает даже версия 1.0.